# Min Values in each row of selected columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a rather simple task but seems like all online help is not working.
I have data set like this:

```
ID   |  Px_1       | Px_2
theta|  106.013676 | 102.8024788702673
Rho  |  100.002818 | 102.62640389123405
gamma|  105.360589 | 107.21999706084836
Beta |  106.133046 | 115.40449479551263
alpha|  106.821119 | 110.54312246081719
```

I want to find min by each row in a fourth col so the output I can have is for example, theta is 102.802 because it is the min value of both Px_1 and Px_2

I tried this but doesnt work
I constantly get max value

```
df_subset = read.set_index('ID')[['Px_1','Px_2']]
d = df_subset.min( axis=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: You get the max value by using the `min` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
df["min"] = df[["Px_1", "Px_2"]].min(axis=1)
```

Select the columns needed, here `["Px_1", "Px_2"]`, to perform `min` operation.